# Mavericks menu bar Wi-Fi icon does not refresh

Tags: wifi

In Mac OS X 10.9, once I am connected to a Wi-Fi station the menu bar Wi-Fi icon no longer refresh (the spinning wheel does not appear). This complicates station switching as I have to turn off and on the Wi-Fi.

Do you know how to revert this behavior to how it worked in Mac OS X 10.8, or an alternative tool to make Wi-Fi connections?

Update: As I mention  below, I realized that rebooting the machine the Wifi icon refreshes until I Fast Switch to another account. In this precise moment it stop working.

Comment: Do you have the "looking for Networks" wheel turning when you click on the WiFi icon? Also, try holding the alt key and click.

Comment: I have added to the post that "the spinning wheel does not appear"

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Next question: If you use the Join Other networks does it scan?, Also if you hold the alt and click on the wifi at the bottom there will be Open Wireless diagnostics- in there select the Window tab- Utility and scan.

Comment: Alt-clicking the Wi-Fi icon shows extended information about the current connection but does not rescan. Does your Mac OS X 10.9 rescan when you click the Wi-Fi icon? My Mac OS X 10.8 and early did it, but Mac OS X 10.9 no longer rescan.

Comment: I have the 10.9.5 on a MacBook Air, and yes it does rescan when I click on the WiFi Icon (there is a very small delay before it starts scanning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few steps to try-

A- To check your functionality  run the

```
airport -s
```

in Terminal.

That should show you the scan results.

B- If there are no results check your hardware profile in About this Mac (this is mine)

Card Type: AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0xE9)
  Firmware Version: Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
  MAC Address:  14:10:9f:f0:29:8c

Check the com.apple.airport.airportutility.plist for been up to date (recent) or just delete it.

C- If above worked then your WiFi Icon in the menu bar is broken.

Press and hold the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key and drag the WiFi Icon to desktop (and it will vanish).

Restart.

Go to

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras
```

And click on

> AirPort.menu

That will bring your WiFi Icon back (hopefully working this time).

Comment: This partially solve the problem. If I cmd-drag the WiFi icon and reboot, the WiFi icon works. I realized that it works until I Fast Switch to another account. In this precise moment it stop working. BTW, I cannot find the file com.apple.airport.airportutility.plist in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.airport.airportutility.plist or any other place.

Comment: Great, it solves the problem! The new problem with fast user switching should be new question. I would recommend you post it with Console report so to see what is going on at that time stamp. It is not in System (~) Library, just copy my line from the answer.

Comment: Repair both Users accounts ACL's.